# Remove the double quotes at the starting of the csv file when using apache commons

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons

I am reading a csv file which has blank lines in between and writing to a csv file with out the empty rows using the apache commons library.
I have the csv file as follows with column names.

```
Username  Password  Amount  Timestamp  
AA, yes, "12,100",   11:30  
AB, No, "13,900", 12:30  
--empty row--  
, ,"14,000", 10:40
```

After reading to the csv file and writing to the file there is double quotes being added to the beginning of the record where there is as null value as:

```
"", ,"14,000", 10:40
```

Please let me know how to print the record without the double quotes. my code is as below.

```
String CSV_File_Path = "Sample.csv";
CSVConversion records = new CSVConversion(CSV_File_Path);
List<CSVRecord> csvRecords = records.getRecords();
BufferedWriter writer =
    Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("Sample2.csv"));

CSVPrinter csvPrinter =
    new CSVPrinter(
        writer,
        CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(
            "Username",
            "Password",
            "Amount",
            "Timestamp"));
            
csvPrinter.printRecords(csvRecords);
csvPrinter.flush();
csvPrinter.close();
```

Comment: Have you tried to check _why_ it prints empty quotes there? The issue is most likely in your `CSVConversion` class, not the printer.

Comment: CSVParser parser = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(in); This is what i do in my CSVConversion class